# I don't understand why I don't get a bug when I initialize a pointer with *p1, where p1 is a double pointer

Tags: c, list, pointers, ampersand, double-pointer

The program doesn't have a specific function; I am just currently studying lists and I have a hard time understanding why I don't get a compile error in line where `Node *curr = *root;` Shouldn't I initialize `Node *curr` with an address using `&`? But when I set a double pointer and a pointer and I initialize the second one with `*p`, where `p` is the double pointer, I get a compile error and the program doesn't even run. Both scenarios seem the same to me, and I can't see the difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
   
typedef struct Node {
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void insert_end(Node **root, int value) {

    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->x = value;

    //We have to use the loop to reach the
    //  end of the list where we add our additional box
    Node *curr = *root;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = new_node;
}

int main() {
     Node *root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
     root->x = 15; //1o element
     root->next = NULL;

    //the last element of a list is always initialized with null
    //exit loop when *next = NULl

    //it matters the order of freeing the memory
    insert_end(&root, -2);
    for (Node *curr = root; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Shouldnt i initialize Nodecurr with an address using &?" --> that is one way.  Another is to initialize with a pointer, like this code does.

Comment: if i initialize this way the double pointer does he now  points directly  to the variable which address has the *pointer?

Comment: It would be good to disambiguate your two uses of `root`. One is `Node **root` while the other is `Node *root`. For example, it would be clearer if the former were `Node **proot` (for 'pointer to root').

Comment: @JOHNBOURAS [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77836188/i-dont-understand-why-i-dont-get-a-bug-when-i-initialize-a-pointer-with-p1-w?noredirect=1#comment137220552_77836188) is unclear.

Comment: In the function `inset_end`:  The type of `curr` is `Node *`.  The type of `root` is `Node **`.  So the type of `*root` is `Node *`.  The types match.  They are compatible pointers.  The assignment is valid C.  It might help if you read a good C tutorial, focusing on pointers.  You just need to learn the syntax, and apply some basic reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `root` in `insert_end` has type `Node **root`: it is a pointer to a `Node` pointer.  It is a tad confusing to use the same name `root` for this thing in `insert_end` and in `main` where `root` is a `Node *` pointing to the first node of the list.

`Node *curr` defines a pointer to iterate on the list and find the last `Node` in order to append the newly allocate node as the `next` element of said last node.  You must use `curr = *root` to start the iteration at the first node.

Note however that one should test if `curr` is a null pointer to avoid undefined behavior when testing `curr->next` on an empty list.

Here is a modified version with more explicit names:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
   
typedef struct Node {
    int x;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void append_node(Node **root_p, int value) {

    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("allocation error\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->x = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    Node *curr = *root_p;
    if (curr == NULL) {
        // list is empty
        *root_p = new_node;
    } else {
        // list is not empty: find the last node
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = new_node;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // start with an empty list
    Node *root = NULL;

    // append 2 nodes
    append_node(&root, 15);
    append_node(&root, -2);

    // print node values
    for (Node *curr = root; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->x);
    }
    // it does not matter the order of freeing the memory
    while (root != NULL) {
        Node *curr = root;
        root = curr->next;
        free(curr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why I don't get a bug when I initialize a pointer with *p1, where p1 is a double pointer

Well, a *double pointer* is a pointer to a pointer. If `p1` is such a thing, a double pointer,  then `*p1` is a pointer. This is `C`. If `*p1` is a pointer, why would it be a problem to initialize a pointer with its value?

if `symbol` is `char****` then

- `*symbol` is `char***`
- `**symbol` is `char**`
- `***symbol` is `char*`
- `****symbol` is a `char`

It is dereferencing...

#### example

This program changes the value of the `int` in `Node` using pointers to pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
} Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node one = {1};

    Node*    pNode    = &one;
    Node**   ppNode   = &pNode;
    Node***  pppNode  = &ppNode;
    Node**** ppppNode = &pppNode;

    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);
    pNode->x = 42;
    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);
    (**ppNode).x = 43;
    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);
    (***pppNode).x = 45;
    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);
    (****ppppNode).x = 46;
    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);

    (****ppppNode).x = 47; // ****ppppNode is Node
    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);

    (***ppppNode)->x = 48; // ***ppppNode is Node*
    printf("value in node is %d\n", one.x);
    return 0;
}
```

#### output

```
value in node is 1
value in node is 42
value in node is 43
value in node is 45
value in node is 46
value in node is 47
value in node is 48
```

It may help to understand that in `C` you declare a name as a type. If `p1` is a pointer to a pointer to `Node` then you declare `p1`. A name. As being of a type: `Node**`.You do not declare `**p1`. The type is `Node**`. So the declaration is

```
    Node**                          p1;
```

because it is `p1` the name you are declaring and `Node**` the type, as the compiler would tell you. For the compiler the spaces are irrelevant.

If `p1` is `Node**` then

- `*p1` is `Node*`
- `**p1` is `Node`

It is the pointer being dereferenced. It is `C`. But it is not what you are declaring. You are declaring a name as a type. The name is `p1`. The type is `Node**`. So

```
    Node                            **p1;
```

Is ok but it is more of a consequence of `p1` being of the type is is. It makes you mentally de-reference the pointer as you read the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Leta give these things values for clarity.

In `main()` lets say the stack starts at address 100000. Local variable `root` is allocated there, so its address is 1000000.

`malloc()` returns something from the heap, lets say it's address 100, so `root` contains 100.

You call `insert_end()`, the parameters are put on the stack, so there's a new version of `root` local to `insert_end()`. Say `main()` needed a total of 8 bytes for local storage, and stack storage is extended downward (decreasing addresses) so the parameters for `insert_end()` are allocated at addresses 99992 (first parameter `root`) and 99988 (second parameter `value`).

`root` in `main()` and `root` in `insert_end()` are different variables with different contents. The content of `root` in `inssert_end()` is the address of `root` in `main()`, which is 100000.

Down below, you're assigning `*root` to `curr`, so you're following the address 100000 in `root` in `insert_end()` to `root` in `main()` and taking that value - 100. You're assigning 100 into `curr`, so `curr` references the memory you originally got from `malloc()`.

To understand better, consider the type of `root` is `Node **`, when you add a `*` to a pointer variable, you remove it from the type, so `*root` is of type `Node *`, and that's the same as `Node *curr`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line on the `insert_end()` function

```
Node*curr=*root;
```

`root` is already a memory address, so it would be redundant to initialize it using an `&`, although you can do it.

> But when I set a double pointer and a pointer and I initialize the second one with *p, where p is the double pointer, I get a compile error and the program doesn't even run.

I don't really understand what you mean by that, but if you mean using

```
Node**curr=*root;
```

See, on your first example, `root` is the address of the head of your linked list, of type `Node**` (pointer to a pointer). using `*root` dereferences that pointer and now we have a pointer to a single node, of type `Node*`. On your assignment, `curr` is now a pointer to a node that points to the same node as `*root`.

On the second example, `curr` would be a pointer to a pointer of a node, that is, a `Node**`, in simpler words, it would point the address of a node. `*root`, on the other hand, would be a `Node*`, that is, it would point to a node itself.

It's easy to see how this would cast an error because of the type mismatch, and this is probably what's generating your compile error.

Your post was a bit confusing, so i don't know if this is the answer you were looking for, you should be a little more clear and provide some example of the errors you're getting next time!